# How to delete or flag one's own comment?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, bug

After due consideration, I'd like to delete one or more of my own comments because they serve no site-valuable purpose. I don't find any means to do so, however. Plan B was to flag the comment(s) for deletion, giving a suitable explanation for said flagging. I also find no means to do that.

What can I do to clean up my own wayward tracks? Does any such mechanism exist? If none, could we add a means of at least flagging said comment(s) for deletion such that, if any there exist any replies relying upon said comment(s), such replies losing all meaning if said comment(s) get deleted, at least a moderator could examine the situation and take appropriate action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover your mouse over the comment, you should see the `X` button, which deletes the comment.
[image]

Similar screenshot from StackOverflow.
[image]

P.S.  This is a bit of a modern UI, where a function is hidden until you get close to it.

Comment: Ah! THERE it is. I was looking for a "delete" on the right or a mouseover on the left as one finds on all other comments. I'm quite familiar with mouseovers - I've been writing them for years - just didn't spot this one because I didn't know where to hover or look. Thanks.